# Links break flow in flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm having an issue with links seeming to break the normal flow in Flexbox.

When I display set to Flexbox, there are two problems with the link formatting.  The space to the left of the link collapses, and there is a huge line break after the link.

I've searched around but can't find any info, and I believe everything is correct with my code.  Is this a known bug?

```css
div {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  font-size:5vw;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  outline:solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Here is some text.  Here is a <a href="#"> link.</a> Here is some more text.  
</div>
```

I'm expecting the links to not cause a line break.

Comment: It is caused by the `height: 100vh`. If the container is the full screen's height, it will `align-items: center` causing the spacing.

Answer (score 0):

For what you apparently want to achieve (wrapping text including links) flex-wrap is really not the right way to go. The large distance between the wrapped text lines is due to your defined `height`– it doubles/multiplies when the contents are wrappen

I would just use `text-align: centered` and some padding, as follows:

```css
div {
  font-size:5vw;
  text-align: center;
  outline:solid 1px black;
  padding: 20vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Here is some text.  Here is a <a href="#"> link.</a> Here is some more text.  
</div>
```